# PL/SQL Trigger on INSTERT OR UPDATE : ":NEW" IS NULL => ambiguous?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm quite a newbie in `PL/SQL` and I'm trying to do quite complex data integrity checks via triggers.

I've already understood how to avoid problems when calling a table inside a trigger that is used on the same table (via a temporary external table) but now I'm facing a really mind-blowing problem : I thought that `":NEW"` was referencing the value in my table `AFTER` an update but things don't look that simple... It is the new value `SET` by the update or insert... which looks to be `NULL` if nothing has been specified, even if the corresponding field value is `NOT NULL` after the update... wich is driving me crazy.

My trigger is set when inserting or updating several variables :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INS_UP_INSTRUMENT_EVENT 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF EVENT_ID, DATE_BEGIN,DATE_END,INSTR_ID,TYPE_EVENT_ID ON AIS_INSTRUMENT_EVENT
```

But now... If there already is a line with non-null fields and I do an

```
UPDATE AIS_INSTRUMENT_EVENT SET INSTR_ID='642' WHERE EVENT_ID='6479'
```

I actually get a `":NEW.DATE_BEGIN"` which is `NULL`... event thought nor the older or newer values are NULL (because I just didn't update it).

How can I distinguish - in my trigger - the case when the `DATE_BEGIN` is updated and `SET` voluntary to `NULL` from the case in which nothing has been specified (and this field must thus remain the same but not necessarily NULL...). I have to many possible combination to check one by one...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: it would help if you could provide a complete test case for what you're trying to do (i.e. the DDL for your table(s) and trigger, along with input data and expected output; N.B. this doesn't have to be your exact tables (e.g. we don't care what the columns/table/trigger are called), but it does need to reproduce the issue you're trying to solve). What is making you think the `:new` value is null?

Comment: Sorry I think I made a to quick conclusion... The bug was mine. I've tested on a "Toy" table and, indeed, the :NEW was not null, even when not set by the UPDATE. I found the bug in the meantime. All this is too new to me ;-). Sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is not true. :new contains the full row regardless whether the column is referenced in the UPDATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test (test INTEGER, last_changed DATE);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INS_UP_TEST 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF test, last_changed ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line('LAST CHANGED IS ' || :new.last_changed);
END;

INSERT INTO test (test, last_changed) VALUES  (1, SYSDATE);

COMMIT;

UPDATE test SET test = test + 1;
```

DBMS Output:

```
LAST CHANGED IS 01.09.17
```

To achieve what you want the mechanism works slightly different. You have to look at two different use cases:

1.) You want the trigger not to fire unless a certain column is mentioned. This use cases is by the reference in the trigger declaration (INSERT OR UDATE OF "column_name"). If the INSERT/UPDATE statement only affects columns that are not mentioned the trigger will not fire.

2.) You want the trigger not to fire unless a certain row is modified. So you want the trigger to only if fire is a value has actually changed. This is done by the WHEN restriction of the trigger. It is usually used in conjunction with DECODE, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INS_UP_TEST 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF test, last_changed ON test  
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (DECODE(new.test,old.test,0,1)=1 OR DECODE(new. last_changed,old. last_changed,0,1)=1)
BEGIN 
   ...
END;
```

So to answer your original question: If you want to the trigger too only fire in cases where the column DATE_BEGIN is set to NULL you will have to declare your trigger using both approaches

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INS_UP_INSTRUMENT_EVENT 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF DATE_BEGIN ON AIS_INSTRUMENT_EVENT
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (DECODE(new.DATE_BEGIN,old. DATE_BEGIN,0,1)=1 AND new.DATE_BEGIN IS NULL)
```

The limitation to certain columns ("INSERT OR UPDATE OF DATE_BEGIN") is not strictly necessary but it is good practice since it improves performance since it excludes the trigger from firing at all.